# Reduzir tamanho da imagem

Tags: media-queries

Não consigo reduzir o tamanho dessa imagem via css.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" id="mainNav" data-toggle="affix">
    <div class="container">
      <a class=" navbar-brand smooth-scroll" href="index.html">
        <img class="imagem" src="img/logo-s.png" alt="logo">
      </a> 
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
```

/* CSS */
@media(max-width: 480px;){
        .navbar .imagem img{
            height: 10px;
        }
    }

Comment: O seletor `.navbar .imagem img` está errado. Deveria ser `.navbar img.imagem` ou apenas `.navbar .imagem`.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro que use a classe da imagem ou até mesmo atribuir um id, lembrando que se houver imagens com a mesma classe, todas elas vão sofrer alterações.

```
 @media(max-width: 480px;){ 
     .imagem{ 
          height: 10px; 
       } 
 }
```

Comment: Funcionou.
Muito obrigado.
Usei id.

Comment: fico feliz por ter ajudado, agradecia se pude-se confirmar a resposta.